# Measurability of a random variable w.r.t a $\sigma$ algebra

Tags: measure-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-analysis, stopping-times, measurable-functions

I've been finding some problems with this exercise on stopping times.

Let X a random variable on $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\{\mathcal{F_t}\}_{t\in T},\mathbb{P})$ filtered space and let $\tau$ a stopping time. Prove that $X$ is $\mathcal{F}_\tau$-measurable if and only if $X\textbf{1}_{\{\tau=n\}}$ is $\mathcal{F}_n$-measurable for all $n$.

Edit:

($\Rightarrow$) assume that $X$ is $\mathcal{F}_\tau$-measurable and that takes value on the space $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$, then we have that events of the form $\{X\in A\}$ for some $A\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ satisfies $\{X\in A\}\cap\{\tau\leq n\}\in\mathcal{F}_n$ for all $n$.Then we want to prove that the r.v. $X\textbf{1}_{\tau=n}:(\Omega,\mathcal{F}_n)\to (\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$. Let $B\in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ we have that:
\begin{equation}
\{X\textbf{1}_{\{\tau=n\}}\in B\}=
\begin{cases}
\{X\in B\}\cap\{\tau=n\} \ \ \ \text{if} \ 0\notin B\\
(\{X\in B\}\cap\{\tau=n\})\cup(\{X=0\}\cup\{\tau\neq n\}) \ \ \ \text{if} \ 0\in B\\
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
Now in the first case we have that since by hyothesis $\{X\in B\}\in\mathcal{F}_\tau$ we have that $\{X\in B\}\cap\{\tau\leq n\}\in\mathcal{F}_n$ and then:
\begin{equation}
\{X\in B\}\cap\{\tau=n\}=\{X\in B\}\cap\{\tau\leq n\}\cap\{\tau\leq n-1\}^c\in\mathcal{F}_n
\end{equation}
In the second case we have just to prove that $\{X=0\}\cup\{\tau\neq n\}\in\mathcal{F}_n$. First it is easy to see that $\{X=0\}\in\mathcal{F}_\tau$, then:
\begin{equation}
\{X=0\}\cup\{\tau\neq n\}=\{X=0\}\cup\{\tau=n\}^c=\{\{X=0\}^c\cap\{\tau=n\}\}^c
\end{equation}
Where the last $\in\mathcal{F}_n$ using same argument of before we conclude.

($\Leftarrow$) Assume now that $X\textbf{1}_{\tau=n}$ is $\mathcal{F}_n$-measurable. Then let $A\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ we want to check that $\{X\in A\}\in\mathcal{F}_\tau$. Thus we have to prove that:
\begin{equation}
\{X\in A\}\cap\{\tau\leq n\}\in\mathcal{F}_n
\end{equation}
Now we have that: $\{X\in A\}=\bigcup_{k\in\mathbb{N}}\{X\in A\}\cap\{\tau=k\}$ where all the events $\{X\in A\}\cap\{\tau=k\}\in\mathcal{F}_k$. Now we conclude:
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\{X\in A\}\cap\{\tau\leq n\}&=\bigg\{\bigcup_{k\in\mathbb{N}}\{X\in A\}\cap\{\tau=k\}\bigg\}\cap\{\tau\leq n\}\\
&=\bigcup_{k\leq n}\{X\in A\}\cap\{\tau=k\} \in\mathcal{F}_n
\end{split}
\end{equation}

I've tried to compute the proof but I'm not completely sure on the first implication, can someone help me?

Comment: Is $T$ discrete?

Comment: Yes $\tau$ is discrete

Comment: Not $\tau, T.{}$

Comment: Sorry, T  is not a discrete set

Comment: Note that $\tau$ is a $T$-valued random object. So your $n$ is actually running over a continuous interval? If that is the case, I suspect the result is false. When $T$ is discrete, you can think of $T=\mathbf{Z}_+$ and then you use that $\tau=n$ if and only if $\tau \leq n$ and $\tau \leq n-1.$ Then, $\tau$ is a stopping time if and only if $\tau= n$ is $\mathscr{F}_n$ measurable for each $n.$ The result is relatively easy after this remark.